# get content from json api to post

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-json-api

i am trying to get post from json api from a non wordpress site

and i want to post the content to my wordpress site.

currently trying with 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/

above plugin but so far no luck, can anybody suggest me about this.

the api i am trying is

here is my api documentation: http://developers.hasoffers.com/#/affiliate

Answer (score 0):

why are you using plugin to fetch data, simply use the jqeury ajax function or jquery get method save the data into the wordpress post. like:-

```
 $.get( "https://api.hasoffers.com/v3/Affiliate_Affiliate.json?Method=getAccountManager&api_key=MY_API_KEY&NetworkId=SAMPLE", function( data ) {

  do what ever you to with data, insert to post or whatever    
});
```

Comment: Hi @DEV thanks for quick response, can you elaborate how to do this. sorry i am little bit new to here

Comment: Yes sure, use the above request in your document.ready function and under function(data) use console.log(data).

Comment: you can see the data coming and use that data as what you want

Comment: and don't forget to apply api key and network id in the url

Comment: do i need to to paste the code in functions.php ? 
or some where else. 

sorry for this i already told i am new to this jquery 

can you show tutorial page or something else to do this.

Comment: No dear, you put this cody anywhere, it will work. And for example I am editing my answer.. you check that